Do you know this circuit?
I was checking the flipper Zero Wi-Fi Developer Board schematics and in the power section I bumped with this circuit, but I've never saw it before. Someone knows the name of the circuit or its purpose.


Hi ... could you edit in a link to the original please?

The 2 PNPs form a simple comparator; comparing the emitter voltages.
When the 3V3 level is higher than ext_3V3, the right-hand PNP will have a higher VBE than the left-hand one (since the bases are tied together); with only 18 mV extra voltage or more, it will conduct twice a much as the left-hand one (which is biased with (3.3-0.7)/100k. Therefore it will pull its collector and 100k load up high -- within VCEsat (~ 0.2 V) of the 3.3V rail. This will turn off the PMOS device (its VGS will only be ~ 0.2 V).
The opposite happens when 3V3 is lower -- the PNP turns off, and the PMOS switch is turned on.
There is a slight caveat -- when the PMOS turns on, it shorts the two supplies together. This makes the V difference nearly zero. Depending in the application, and if reverse current is required, you need to decide if this condition should allow the PMOS to remain on. If it does, then you need to ensure that the 'offset' of the comparator allows that. This is controllable by changing the ratio of the two 100k resistors.
